# Python 3.4においてGlobalなListもしくはDict オブジェクトを定義する方法について

Tags: python, python3

以下のコードで実行したところ、local_testの実行前後でglobal_listの要素が変化してしまいました。
local_testの実行前後でglobal_listの要素を変更しない方法はありますでしょうか？
有る場合、どのようにコードを修正すればよいでしょうか？

環境：Python3.4.3

```py
global_list = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4
]

def local_test():
  list = global_list
  list.append(5)
  print(list)

print(global_list)  # [1,2,3,4]
local_test()  # [1,2,3,4,5]
print(global_list)  # [1,2,3,4,5]
# 期待する出力
print(global_list)  # [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

既に回答がありますが、`global_list` そのものではなく、そのリストのコピーを利用するのが回避策です。
リストにはコピーメソッドがあるので、

```
- list = global_list
+ list = global_list.copy()
```

とするだけで目的の結果が得られます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。そして初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。copy関数を使用すれば解決できたのですね。

Answer (score 2):

自分だったら、こうするかなと思います。

```
global_list = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4
]

def local_test():
  local_list = global_list + [5]
  print(local_list)

print(global_list)  # [1,2,3,4]
local_test()  # [1,2,3,4,5]
print(global_list)  # [1,2,3,4]
```

list の足し算は、元となった list の中身を変更することなく、結果は新しい list が得られるからです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。足し算だとGlobal変数を変更しないのですね。なぜこのような差が生じるのかが理解できていないですが、足し算であれば変更されないと理解しました。